# Какой выбрать file_id от файлов бота в telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Добрый день! Пишу бота для telegram на php, прицеплен через webhook.
Бот уже умеет отправлять файлы через url. Но не хотелось бы раз за разом отсылать их повторно.

Не могу понять, как:

1. получить file_id его файлов, отправленных ранее.
   (пытаюсь делать форвард сообщения бота, выводя в канал

```
$output = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
sendMessage($chat_id, $output['message']['photo'][0]['file_id']);
sendMessage($chat_id, $output['message']['photo'][1]['file_id']);
sendMessage($chat_id, $output['message']['photo'][2]['file_id']);
```

выходят три разных маркера вида `AgADBAAD1acxG_hEyFKdehxkDtYNbECcpxkABKdphgFcKKFpkRMAAgI`, как понять, который из них мне нужен? или, может быть при форварде используется другой маркер, непонятно, другого метода не придумал пока)

2. как их использовать? пытаюсь так:

```
$api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $access_token;
function sendPhotoId($chat_id, $file) {
    $target_url = $GLOBALS['api'] . '/sendphoto';
    $post = array(
        'chat_id'   => $chat_id,
        'photo'     => array(
            'file_id' => "AgADBAAD1acxG_hEyFKdehxkDtYNbECcpxkABOusfARhbKj6kxMAAgI"
        )
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

Но не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать.

Comment: Судя по [описанию в документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto), в методе **sendPhoto** в качестве параметра **photo** вы должны передавать просто строку с id файла, а не объект.

Comment: Сначала пробовала строкой. 'photo'     => "AgADBAAD1acxG_hEyFKdehxkDtYNbECcpxkABOusfARhbKj6kxMAAgI" в составе массива post. Тоже не работает.

Comment: А у меня работает https://pastebin.com/Uq7LEGC4. Вывод ошибок бы хоть включили, а то не ясно ничего!

Comment: Как включить вывод ошибок?
Ага, если у вас работает, значит, вероятно, проблема в неправильно определенном id файла, то есть проблема 1.

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/228074 Попробуйте протестировать вашу функцию sendPhotoId, запуская её из консольки. Запишите её отдельно в файл и запустите скрипт.

Answer (score 1):

> Как понять, который из идентификаторов файлом мне нужен для пересылки фотографий?

Лучше используйте **file_id** фотографии самого большого разрешения. Хоть это явно и не зафиксировано в документации, но фотки записываются в массиве в порядке возрастания линейных размеров. Так что надо брать самый последний айдишник из переданных.

В примере вашем, как уже было отмечено, неправильно заполняется массив с параметрами. Поле **photo** должно содержать только строку — id отправляемого фото *(ну или ссылку, или байты файла в формате multipart/form-data).* Так сказано в описании метода [sendPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto).

Кроме того, учтите, что бот может таким образом отправлять только те **file_id**, которые он сам получил от телеграма. Чужие, от другого бота, не подойдут.

На этом всё, касаемо особенностей Telegram. Из возможных проблем стоит также рассмотреть отсутствие библиотеки curl. Чтобы её установить в Ubuntu или Debian, поставьте пакет [php-curl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php-curl).

Comment: он  сам получил - это значит что мне надо **ему** отправить файл, снять из полученного сообщения file_id и его использовать при отправке? я пока что пытаюсь использовать те, которые он сам до этого отправил (через sendPhoto и url), но не работает.

Comment: Под словом «получил» имелось ввиду, что id файла пришёл от сервера Telegram именно для данного бота. Чужие файлы не получится переотправить.